# Embedded Vimeo video will not play in a PhoneGap app, but same HTML works without PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, vimeo

I'm using PhoneGap / Cordova 1.5.0, this is my HTML page:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38799240?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Using a Motorola Droid 2 with Android OS 2.3.3 installed, if I pull this HTML page up in a normal browser I can play the video as expected.

But, if I make that HTML my index.html page in a PhoneGap project I can see the video thumbnail and the play button, but tapping on it only turns the play button to a spinner for a second, and the video doesn't play.

I found a few posts that make it sound like it's an access origin issue, some said you can use a wildcard like `*`, others said it's like a perl regex, so you use a regex wildstar, ie: `.*`,  I tried many versions in my res/xml/cordova.xml file like:

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
<access origin="http://player.vimeo.com*"/>
<access origin="http://*.vimeocdn.com*" />
<access origin="http://*.vimeo.com*" />
<access origin="http://vimeo.com*" />
```

Which doesn't seem to have an effect.

I haven't tested this in an iPhone PhoneGap environment yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Try just putting `http://*` and if that works, then you can be fairly confident that it's an access origin issue.

Comment: But it's probably not a good idea to leave `http://*` in there, try to figure out the exact urls you need to have in there.

Comment: @appclay Tried `http://*` and `http://.*`, no dice.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Was there ever a solution to this?  I'm having the same issue in PhoneGap 2.0 on Android.  Works fine on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

you can't include external video (vimeo/youtube) in phonegap like that.
you need to be pointing to the actual video or simply open the video you already have in childbrowser (using an image with a videostill as trigger would be nice).

Answer (score 0):

I am able to play Vimeo videos using iFrame tag in my iOS app which is also phonegap based. I am using Phonegap 3.2.0 here. Below is the code I am using

```
NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\body {\background-color: #000000;\
color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<iframe width=\"512\" height=\"374\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/60331941\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlVideo];

[customWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

I have whitelisted below urls in my config.xml file.

```
<access origin="*.vimeo.com" />
<access origin="*.vimeocdn.com" />
```

I have written this code inside a phonegap plugin class. So, I am able to write objective-C code here. But the same could be done in html file also.

Hope it helps in some way !!